# Proof for property of derivation operator for formal context: $A_1\subseteq A_2 \implies A^{'}_2\subseteq A^{'}_1$.

Tags: solution-verification, lattice-orders, data-analysis

I wanted to verify the validity of my proof for the property of derivation operator for [formal context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis#Formal_contexts_and_concepts:%7E:text=to%20express%20incidence.-,Concept%20lattice%20of%20a%20formal%20context,-%5Bedit%5D).
I will not go to detail that much and simply define few things before indroducing the property that is of interest.

$\Bbb{K}=(G,M,I)$ is formal context where $G$ and $M$ are sets of objects and attributes, respectively, and $I$ is a binary relation from $G$ to $M$.
Derivation operator (in some literatures, it is also known as concept-forming operator), denoted as $(\cdot^{'})$, is given below.
$$
A^{'} = \{m\in M|gIm:\forall g\in A\}, \\
B^{'} = \{g\in G|gIm:\forall m\in B\}
$$
where $A \subseteq G$ and $B \subseteq M$.

There is a property below based on derivation operator given $A_1, A_2 \subseteq G$.

$A_1\subseteq A_2 \implies A^{'}_2\subseteq A^{'}_1$

I will provide, by now, the proof for this property.

**Proof:** let's assume, for contradiction, $A^{'}_2\nsubseteq A^{'}_1$ is true. It implies that $m\in A^{'}_2$ and $m\notin A^{'}_1$. It leads to the statement of *"m is a common attribute for the all objects in $A_2$, that is, $gIm \space \forall g \in A_2$"*. Since $A_1$ is a subset of $A_2$, $m$ is also common attribute for $\forall g \in A_1$. Thus $m\in A_1$ is true. This is a contradiction, since we have provided that $m$ is not in $A_1$ ($m\notin A^{'}_1$). $\qquad\square$

Comment: It is correct, although a direct proof (not by contradiction) is easy to get and essentially all the reasoning is already there in your proof.

Comment: Yeah, by the way, the proof in a textbook was a direct one. And was very short.